# Maven failing due to java.security API warning

Tags: exception, maven-2, jce

`mvn clean package` is failing due to a warning. Is it due to [this](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-59) bug (its fixed though)?  Any suggestions on how to fix this problem.

```
[loading java/security/KeyPairGenerator.class(java/security:KeyPairGenerator.class)]
[loading sun/security/jca/GetInstance.class(sun/security/jca:GetInstance.class)]
[loading sun/security/jca/GetInstance$Instance.class(sun/security/jca:GetInstance$Instance.class)]
[loading java/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpi.class(java/security:KeyPairGeneratorSpi.class)]
[loading java/security/spec/AlgorithmParameterSpec.class(java/security/spec:AlgorithmParameterSpec.class)]
[loading java/security/spec/EncodedKeySpec.class(java/security/spec:EncodedKeySpec.class)]
[loading java/security/spec/KeySpec.class(java/security/spec:KeySpec.class)]
/home/user/common/common-lib/src/main/java/com/org/security/CryptoUtil.java:200: warning: sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
        CertAndKeyGen generator = null;
        ^

/home/user/common/common-lib/src/main/java/com/org/security/CryptoUtil.java:[203,19] sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release

/home/user/common/common-lib/src/main/java/com/org/security/CryptoUtil.java:[205,3] sun.security.x509.X500Name is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
/home/user/common/common-lib/src/main/java/com/org/security/CryptoUtil.java:[205,23] sun.security.x509.X500Name is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release

could not parse error message: [loading sun/security/util/DerInputStream.class(sun/security/util:DerInputStream.class)]
[loading sun/security/util/DerValue.class(sun/security/util:DerValue.class)]
[loading sun/security/x509/RDN.class(sun/security/x509:RDN.class)]
[loading java/security/cert/X509Extension.class(java/security/cert:X509Extension.class)]
[loading java/security/cert/Certificate.class(java/security/cert:Certificate.class)]
[loading java/io/FileDescriptor.class(java/io:FileDescriptor.class)]
[loading java/security/KeyStore$LoadStoreParameter.class(java/security:KeyStore$LoadStoreParameter.class)]
[loading java/security/Key.class(java/security:Key.class)]
[loading java/security/SignatureSpi.class(java/security:SignatureSpi.class)]
[loading java/nio/ByteBuffer.class(java/nio:ByteBuffer.class)]
/home/user/common/common-lib/src/main/java/com/org/security/CryptoUtil.java:400: warning: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64 is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
        out.print( Base64.encode( key.getEncoded() ) );
                   ^

could not parse error message: [loading java/security/Principal.class(java/security:Principal.class)]
[loading javax/security/auth/x500/X500Principal.class(javax/security/auth/x500:X500Principal.class)]
[loading java/io/FileWriter.class(java/io:FileWriter.class)]
[loading java/io/OutputStreamWriter.class(java/io:OutputStreamWriter.class)]
/home/user/common/common-lib/src/main/java/com/org/security/CryptoUtil.java:415: warning: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64 is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
        out.print( Base64.encode( certificate.getEncoded() ) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [comments](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-59?focusedCommentId=170845&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_170845) in the bug link in the question, it looks like the problem occurs when `verbose` is turned on.  Can you check if this is true in your case and if so, check if the error persists if it is turned off?

Comment: yes, i just found the error. turned off verbose and it worked. thanks

Answer (score 1):

By providing the below arguments in the pom.xml of my project solved the issue.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<compilerArguments>
<bootclasspath>${java.home}\lib\rt.jar</bootclasspath>
</compilerArguments>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

But still unclear as to why this works?